# php preg match - how to get html tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, preg-match

there were many threads about it, but I still need help.
I need to use preg_match to get the text I need from HTML tags.

the HTML is:

```
<td>
<center>
<b>
<font face="Arial" color="red">(I need this content)</font>
</b>
</center>
</td>
```

(btw. I solved my problem with domdocument, but I need to use preg_match)

Please, help.

Regards.

Comment: Is the text you're looking for *only* going to be in <font> tags, or can it appear anywhere?  If you have the general area that you know the text will be in, you can use `strip_tags` to remove all the HTML and be left with the desired text.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
<?php
$html = '<td>
<center>
<b>
<font face="Arial" color="red">(I need this content)</font>
</b>
</center>
</td>';

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>/is', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Edit: you may want to include the 'face="Arial" color="red"'-bit in the regexp unless you want to match EVERY font-element's contents. You may also wanna include the `<b>` and  `<center>` elements to narrow the search even further.

On a side note: This HTML looks very dated. Using center and font elements is very, *very* bad practice. So is using tables for layout.

Comment: yeah, it's not my code and this way I need to get the data from an old website.

unfortunately I still get empty array ;/

Comment: That's strange. The code I posted works though... (I've tested it locally).