# Get the html tag in php

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I am looking to get the tag of a specific element in php, and I think I can do that through preg_match, but I am not sure.

Essentially I have something like:

```
<label>Some Jazz</label>
```

What I would like to do is:

*if tag = label then do something, else do something else.*

The problem is getting the label part from the html tag. I did how ever find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594165/php-preg-match-how-to-get-html-tag). How ever your thoughts are welcome.

I failed to mention I do not want the "some jazz" I want to see if the tag is a label or not. - this is in reference to some answers where it gets me whats between the tags and not the tag it's self.

Comment: For your reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404433/get-content-within-a-html-tag-using-php-and-replace-it-after-processing

Comment: If the HTML gets more complicated, you may want to consider using XPath. See example [here](http://www.earthinfo.org/xpaths-with-php-by-example/)

Comment: I would suggest using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it is:

```
<?php

//External html or you can set this by string
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/"); 

//Parse html to object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html); //To prevent some html errors

//Labels
$labels = $doc->getElementsByTagName('label');

//For each label
for ($i = 0; $i < $labels->length; $i++) {

    $label = $labels->item($i);

    //Check label value
    if($label->nodeValue == 'something') {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
        //Do something
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: this doesnt help as I don't care about the value, I care about the tag.

Comment: Ignoring the value part, is not what you're looking for? Through the script I posted an answer you can get the label tag. If you uploaded the html does not have a tag label method `getElementsByTagName` returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of parsing with Simple HTML DOM

```
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
```